# Black lines on edge of youtube embed using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

At maximised screen on Chrome I get annoying black lines on my responsive youtube embeds (tried to post image but no rep).

When paused there is a thin black line at the bottom of the video. When playing there is a slightly thicker black line on the left side of the video.

I am using the responsive code provided by Bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
   <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jO7UfFyGrdk?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is annoying as I want a plain white background in my videos to match the background of my site.

Answer (score 7):

In my responsive container div, I added clip-path: inset(1px 1px); Works for newer browsers except Edge. Only solution I have come up with to remove the black lines from the thumbnail.

```
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed
{ 
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; clip-path: inset(1px 1px);
}
```

Comment: It's utterly insane that this problem could be fixed by setting `body { background-color: white; }` in the YouTube CSS if only they'd give us the option to set the background color. The way that browsers use many decimal places for pixel dimensions and even 3x DPI screens mean it's effectively impossible to size it correctly yourself.

Comment: I'd also recommend adding `iframe { background-color: hotpink; }` (then change it to your actual background after observing a pink flash)!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. After a while I switched from the "iframe" to "video". Here's what I used...

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video class="embed-responsive-item" src="videos/k9pennExample.mp4" type="video/mp4" allowfullscreen controls></video>
</div>
```

NOTE: Make sure add 'autoplay' or 'controls' otherwise you will have an unplayable video.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not YouTube of course. Also you can set the background color for `video` to avoid flickering if your page background is not black.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this woraround:

```
video, iframe{
    opacity: .99;
}
```